# how to escape characters like '[', ']', '|' in regexp_substr oracle

Tags: oracle, escaping, character

i need to replace somthing like this:

```
some random characters[[some_randome_characters1|some_randome_characters2]]some random characters
```

to this:

```
[link=some_randome_characters]some_randome_characters[/link]
```

i manage to write procedure having this:

```
l_tmp:=regexp_substr(content,'/[{2}(/s|/w|/d)+/|/[{2}(/s|/w|/d)+/]{2}');
```

... here i am doing rest stuff to build my link.
Problem is that `(/s|/w|/d)+` dont find all matches -> for exapmle text having '.', or '=', and others. All in all i want to change this:

```
(/s|/w|/d)+
```

to this:

```
[^/|/[/]]
```

But it wont work. Is there any way to escape those 3 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53f0c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extractFirstLink(
  str IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  m1 VARCHAR2(4000) := REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '\[\[(.*?)(\|(.*?))?\]\]', 1, 1, NULL, 1 );
  m2 VARCHAR2(4000) := REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '\[\[(.*?)(\|(.*?))?\]\]', 1, 1, NULL, 3 );
BEGIN
  RETURN '[link=' || m1 || ']' || NVL( m2, m1 ) || '[/link]';
END extractFirstLink;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data AS (
 SELECT 'some random characters[[some_randome_characters1|some_randome_characters2]]some random characters' AS text
 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT extractFirstLink( text )
FROM data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53f0c/1/0)**:

```
|                                         EXTRACTFIRSTLINK(TEXT) |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| [link=some_randome_characters1]some_randome_characters2[/link] |
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the shlash `/` character,
but you must use the backslash `\` to escape a character.